# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object expressionengine

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I have no idea why this error is happening, it's shown in all the expressionengine tutorials and on the forums yet for some reason I still get it? line 43 is shown in the script

```
class upload_pictures
{
    public function upload_pictures()
    {
        if (!isset($whats_gonna_happen))
        {
            $uploads='';
            $cout=1;
            if (!table_exists('albums'))
            {
                                    //line 43 below
                $this->EE->db->query("CREATE TABLE albums(
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                    name VARCHAR(50)
                ") or die(mysql_error());
            }
            $stuff=$this->EE->db->query('SELECT id, name FROM albums');
```

Comment: See related. `$this->EE->db` is `null`. I'd check where that gets setup.

Comment: Yeah, where is $this->EE even created? it doesn't seem to even be defined as a property of this class. are you sure that the examples you have seen are not using this method from within a different class? the $this keyword always refers to the current class your code is in, and therefor this method call would only work inside of a class that has the property $EE which contains an object, which in turn contains another object in its $db property, and then that object would need to have a method named query().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in expressionengine you need to have the line

`$this->EE=& get_instance();`

in the constructor to get to the superglobals.